# Calculate $\bigl|\frac{1}{n^z}\bigr|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

If $z\in \mathbb C$ calculate:
$$\Bigl|\frac{1}{n^z}\Bigr|$$
with n a natural number.

And suggestion please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which branch of $n^{-z}$ are you using? (Whichever, the crucial thing is to know what $\lvert \exp(w)\rvert$ is.)

Comment: Sorry, butnI don't understand

Comment: For any $a\neq 0$, the function $z \mapsto a^z$ has different branches, one for each value of $\log a$, given by $\exp(z\cdot \log a)$. The absolute value of $n^z$ depends on the chosen value of the logarithm, i.e. the branch of $n^z$. But for all branches, you need to know that $\lvert\exp(w)\rvert = \exp(\operatorname{Re} w)$, so $\lvert a^z\rvert = \exp (\operatorname{Re} (z\log a))$ for the used value of $\log a$. If you use the principal branch of $n^z$, with the real value of $\log n$, you get $\lvert n^z\rvert = n^{\operatorname{Re}z}$, ...

Comment: ... but for a generic branch, $\lvert n^z\rvert = n^{\operatorname{Re} z}\cdot \exp(2\pi k\operatorname{Im} z)$ for some integer $k$. It is a pretty safe bet that the principal branch is meant when nothing is specified, but I wanted to draw attention to the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, $n^z$, for $n\in\mathbb N$, is defined as
$$
n^z=\mathrm{e}^{z\log n}=\mathrm{e}^{\log n\,(\mathrm{Re}\,z+i\,\mathrm{Im}\,z)},
$$ 
and hence
$$
\lvert n^z\rvert=\mathrm{e}^{\log n\,(\mathrm{Re}\,z)}.
$$

Comment: ... which can be simplified back to $n^{{\rm Re}\, z}$